# Gconf profiles personalized with environment variables

Tags: gnome, environment-variables

What is best practice for creating mandatory or default gconf-profiles using the users environment variables. That would make it easy to maintain system-wide profiles and distribute profiles in a corporate network.

For an example, I want to use a Gconf key where some information is defined by environment variables, the key `/apps/evolution/mail/accounts` and `$USER`/`$USERNAME`:

```
[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<account name="$(USER)@example.com">
<identity>
    <name>$(USERNAME)</name>
    <addr-spec>$(USER)@example.com</addr-spec>
</identity>
<source>
  <url>imap://$(USER)%
40example.com@imap.example.com/;;use_ssl=when-possible
 </url>
</source>
<transport save-passwd="true">
        <url>smtp://$(USER)%40smtp.example.com;;use_ssl=when-possible</url>
</transport>

</account>
,
]
```

I believe that I need a subsystem that processes template profiles into something `gconfd` can use. I have tried desktop-profiles and sabayon without any luck. Evoldap-backend works only for evolution and feels a little overkill even if I end up with LDAP / Gosa or LDAP / phamm for authentication. Mail, IM and VoIP / Telepathy uses only information that is easy reachable from GECOS (/etc/passwd) and standard login environment. It feels more robust to administer one system-wide template than a profile per user.

Answer (score 1):

This should be solvable with a simple bash script using standard Linux tools:

1. Check if the folder `/home/"$USER"/.gconf/apps/evolution` exists.
2. If it doesn't exist, copy a template directory over.
3. Replace the placeholders with `sed`.